# Magento 2 - how to skip the cache when getting system config value?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

I'm trying to get config values using:

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
    $config_path,
    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
);
```

& it returns the cached value.
Is there any way to make it skip the cache **without** disabling it?
*I want the cache to be enabled but still bypass it for this value only.
**I also don't want to always clear the cache programmatically before getting it.
-- Any idea?

---

Comment: [UPDATE]
Answered by Oliver De Cramer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208324/magento-2-how-to-skip-the-cache-when-getting-system-config-value/45218230#45218230

Answer (score 3):

you can use below code to get system config value even if caching is enable.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    private $configCollection;

    public function __construct(Context $context,
                                \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data\CollectionFactory $configCollection)
    {
        $this->configCollection = $configCollection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
  
    public function getFieldValue()
    {
        $collection = $this->configCollection->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter("path",['eq'=>"path/section/field"]);
        if($collection->count()>0){
            return $collection->getFirstItem()->getData()['value'];
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }

    }

}
```